# How can I update field defined as date in phpmyadmin with current date every time I execute a query in my web page?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have added a query in my website php page. It looks like something...

```
mysql_select_db("my_db", $con); 

$sq2="INSERT INTO querylog(QueryID, Module, AskedBy, Date)
VALUES
('', '$_POST[Module]', '$_POST[Name]', '')";

$row = !mysql_query($sq2,$con)
```

I want 'Date' column to update automatically in phpmyadmin table. Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: You should stop what you're doing and *immediately* read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You cannot have a site on the internet with code like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either set the default for the column to be `NOW()` or just insert `NOW()` with your query.

```
$sq2 = "INSERT INTO querylog (QueryID, Module, AskedBy, `Date`)
    VALUES ('', '$_POST[Module]', '$_POST[Name]', NOW())";
```

Please, don't use `mysql_` functions in new code. They are no longer maintained and are officially deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be to change your date column to a timestamp.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html

An alternate solution would be to use a trigger.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

In phpMyAdmin open up the SQL tab and paste something like:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER autoSetDate BEFORE INSERT ON yourDatabaseName.yourTableName
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    NEW.date=NOW();
END; $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I used date() of php to get time and date like-            $CurrentDate = date('d-m-Y');                                            /* then use $CurrentDate in sql staement */                               $sq2 = "INSERT INTO querylog (QueryID, Module, AskedBy, `Date`)
    VALUES ('', '$_POST[Module]', '$_POST[Name]', $CurrentDate)";      This is also working...Thanks for solution.